# How to refresh a particular part of a webpage using struts2 framework

Tags: javascript, struts2

How to refresh a particular part of a webpage using struts2 framework 
please help...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something not in scope of Struts2, all you need to have a small JavaScript code which will do your work something like

```
<div id="content"><p>refesh content</p></div>
<a href="divrefresh()">Refresh</a>


function divrefresh() {
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "Div got refreshed"
}
```

Not sure what your use-case is, so there might be other way to do this but only possible when you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Struts2 Jquery Showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/). It uses the [Struts2 Jquery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/).

You can use <sj:div> with reloadTopics and href attributes to dynamically refresh parts of a webpage.

Comment: If use case is simple i will not prefer to add extra dependency for this.Plain java-script will do the work.More over question is not clear what exact he want :)